# How to disable binary ignition?

Tags: ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a binary installation of ignition gazebo fortress, but want to build ignition gazebo garden from source too.

Is there a way to "disable" the binary fortress without uninstalling it? (In ROS, this can be achieved by not sourcing the setup file for the binary version.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28420/how-to-disable-binary-ignition?/) by [ijnek](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/103490/ijnek/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't believe "disabling" is possible since the binaries are installed in system paths that are normally part of your `PATH` environment. However, building garden from source should be possible without uninstalling fortress, i.e, they are meant to be able to coexist side-by-side (python bindings might be an issue, so I'd have a different recommendation if you need to use them).

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2022-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0